# Rotating figure 8 - leaving the path on screen in time intervals

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I would like the figure 8 thats rotating around the center point to print itself (and stay there) along the circle in certain frequencies.

I need to see the overlap printed on the screen and draw its pattern around its orbit.

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);


function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,10,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.rotate(rotation);

    ctx.beginPath();

    for (var t = 0.0; t < 15; t += 0.1){
        console.log(x, y);
        x = Math.sin(t)*20 + 150;
        y = Math.sin(a * t + b)*20 + 150;
        dy = Math.cos(a * t + b) * a;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        if (dy < 0.1 && dy > -0.1)
          ctx.fillRect(x,y,0,0);
        ctx.stroke();
}
    ctx.restore();

    rotation+=Math.PI/50;
}
```

I started a codepen
https://codepen.io/braydendevito/pen/zQEJjz

I'm guessing it needs a loop, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I appreciate it.

Comment: This shows potential, but copy & pasting parts into your example didn't exactly work: https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/10/creating-trail-effect-with-canvas.html

Comment: Interesting potential for sure. Instead of a trail like animation, I'd like the whole '8' to be 'burned' into its orbit, so I can see the overlap at certain times.

Comment: Do you want that "burn" to eventually go away or just continue to get darker?

Comment: Eventually disappearing would be cool. Maybe on the very tail end of the pattern, to show the overlap in real time would be perfect. burning and getting darker shouldn't be an issue since its black anyways.

Comment: I'm thinking you will need to implement "trails", even if it doesn't look like the normal variety. I've been trying to get something similar to https://codepen.io/falldowngoboone/pen/PwzPYv working, but maybe I'm too brain-burnt tonight to get it working, or I'm just out of my scope of knowledge on how to animate objects.

Comment: That trail thing is looking more and more promising. Not to mention, I've been playing with it for hours.... ha ha ha